# WAP to remove duplicates in a list. Why is this wrong?

Tags: python, list

I expected every element to go through the for loop, then the duplicate ones to be removed through the if loop.

```
num = [5, 7, 21, 7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7 , 7]

for i in num:
    if num.count(i)!=1:
        num.remove(i)
print(num)
```

What I get:

```
[21, 7, 5, 7, 7]
```

What I expect:

```
[21, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: The list 'num' is being altered as you're iterating it. Adding values to a new list if it doesn't contain it rather than editing the original would avoid this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are reducing the size of array while iterating on it.
`for i in num` will check for the length of num. After 5 iterations (i=5), the length of num will become 5 and the loop will break.

It's better to always avoid mutating the list you're looping on.

Same result can also be achieved simply by:

```
num = list(set(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

> **list. remove(object)** Removes the first item from the list which matches the specified value.

To solve your purpose we can utilize a data structure name `set` which have property to store multiple items in a single variable.

```
num = [5, 7, 21, 7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7 , 7]
print(set(num))
```

---

If you want to go with your logic instead of using `set` data structure checkout this code

```
num = [5, 7, 21, 7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7 , 7]

res = []
for i in range(len(num)):
    if num.index(num[i])==i:
        res.append(num[i])

print(res)
```

**OR**

```
num = [5, 7, 21, 7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7 , 7]

res = []
for i in num:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)

print(res)
```